# See which users are logged in from lock screen on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, multiple-users

I've recently upgraded from Windows 7 to 10. Now on the lock screen I just see a list of usernames - I can't see which of them is logged in, like I used to on Windows 7. Is there a setting or something that I can do to see that? (If the computer is running slowly I'd like to see who's logged in so I can log in as them and then log out.)

Comment: Why not just log in as an admin and see who's logged in, and optionally log them out (both task can be done in Task Manager)?

Comment: Because it's running slowly, it would just take more time to log in as an admin, see who else is logged in, log out, and then log in as the other user.

Comment: While logged into a user, you can tell which users are already logged in, by the list of users you can switch to.

Comment: I know. I want to find out from the lock screen, without logging in as someone.

Comment: I have a Windows 10 VM, which has multiple accounts, it indicates out of the box which users are logged into it at the lock screen.